# Information Box causing validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have an ASP page in which I have a file uploader. This file uploader has a required field validator attached to it. When I choose the desired file to upload the file uploads successfully and an Information Box appears with a success message.

When I click OK on the Information Box to make it go away, it attempts to validate the whole page again and the Information Box won't disappear.

I have tried setting the CausesValidation property on the file uploader to false but no luck. I've also tried AutoPostBack and IsPostBack.

**aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Title="Excel File Content Upload" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
         CodeBehind="ExcelFileContentUpload.aspx.vb" Inherits="Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.UI.ExcelFileContentUpload" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/GenericControls/UC_InformationMessageBox.ascx" TagName="InformationBox"
    TagPrefix="uc" %><asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Text="Excel File Content Upload" runat="server" />
</h2>
<br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploader" runat="server" Width="400px"/>
<br />
<br />
    Choose Year: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    Choose Month: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnDataUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Data" CssClass="buttonBlue"
                        Visible="true" Width="115px"/>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainContentUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc:InformationBox ID="InformationBox" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfFileUploader" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUploader"
                                        ErrorMessage="* Select an Excel file to upload" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

**Page Load**

```
#Region "PAGE LOAD"
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Load years and months into their respective dropdown lists
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim _currentYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year
            Dim _previousYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year - 1
            Dim _month = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en").DateTimeFormat.MonthNames

            For i As Integer = 0 To _month.Length - 1
                ddlMonth.Items.Add(New ListItem(_month(i), i + 1).ToString())
            Next

            ddlYear.Items.Add(_currentYear)
            ddlYear.Items.Add(_previousYear)
        End If

    End Sub
#End Region
```

Comment: Try using `ValidationGroup` on the validators.

Comment: I tried adding a validation group to the validator but it didn't work.

Comment: You were actually partially correct. I had to add a ValidationGroup onto the btnDataUpload and the same validation group onto the RequiredFieldValidator. If you'd like to post an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Yeah, you need to add it to the button also. Forgot to mention that part, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDataUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Data" CssClass="buttonBlue" Visible="true" Width="115px" ValidationGroup="A" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainContentUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc:InformationBox ID="InformationBox" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfFileUploader" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUploader" ErrorMessage="* Select an Excel file to upload" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="A"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I think another option might be to take the InformationBox out of the UpdatePanel, and put the Button inside the panel, and use the defaultButton property.  That works with asp:Panels easily enough.